# Trie implementation in Guava?

Tags: java, guava, trie

In the past Google Collections included an [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/PrefixTrie.java?r=2) of a `TRIE`. Is there any TRIE implementation in Guava? I need an efficient way to find common prefixes in a set of strings.

Comment: Please upvote this [issue#10](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/10) Trie interface(s) and implementation(s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any TRIE implementation in Guava?

No.  (IIRC, this is more or less because tries are an awfully general data structure, and we haven't had the data, resources, or demand to design an API up to Guava's usual standards?)

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=10